# Проблема с кодом в С#

Tags: c#, массивы

Пишет, что m, n, k не существуют в данном контексте, но когда объявляю их ничего не происходит.

Вот само задание:

> Задан двумерный массив чисел (используйте генератор случайных чисел). Отсортируйте каждую нечетную строку по возрастанию, а каждую четную – по убыванию, после чего выведите значение k-го столбца.

```
    `var arr = new int[n][];
     var rand = new Random();
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
     { 
     arr[i] = new int[m]; 
     for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
     arr[i][j] = rand.Next(100); 
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
     Array.Sort(arr[i], (x, y) => ((i & 1) == 0) ? y - x : x - y);
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
     Console.WriteLine(arr[i][k]);
     Console.ReadLine();`
```

Comment: `m, n, k не существуют в данном контексте` — верно, так и есть. `но когда объявляю их ничего не происходит` — покажите как

Comment: `static void Main(string[] args)
 {
 int n = 0;
 var arr = new int[n][];
 var rand = new Random();
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
 {

                int m = 0;
                arr[i] = new int[m]; 
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
                    arr[i][j] = rand.Next(100); 
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
                Array.Sort(arr[i], (x, y) => ((i & 1) == 0) ? y - x : x - y);
            int k = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i][k]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }`

Comment: А что должно произойти, если n = 0? Что вообще обозначает n в вашем коде?

Comment: Если честно, то я сама не знаю. Мне помогли написать этот код для задания. Но он не сработал

Comment: Простите, но мы тут двоечникам не помогаем, нам вас потом ещё на работу к себе нанимать, зачем нам такие коллеги, которые не будут решать задачи?